# Dynamically assigning attributes using strings as attribute setters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, attr-accessor

I have a hash of name / value pairs:

```
attr_hash = {"attr1"=>"val1","attr2=>"val2"}
```

I want to cycle through each one of these values and assign them to an object like so:

```
thing = Thing.new
attr_hash.each do |k,v|
  thing.k = v
end

class Thing
   attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2
end
```

The problem of course being that attr1 is and attr2 are strings.. So I can't do something like `thing."attr1"`

I've tried doing:
`thing.send(k,v)` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `thing.send("#{k}=", v)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the setter method, which for an attribute called `name` would be `name=`.
Following from your example:

```
attr_hash.each do |k,v|
  thing.send("#{k}=", v)
end
```

Also, if this hash is coming from the user somehow, it might be a good idea to test if the setter exists before calling it, using `respond_to?`:

```
attr_hash.each do |k,v|
  setter = "#{k}="
  thing.send(setter, v) if thing.respond_to?(setter)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) does it for you.

```
require 'ostruct'
attr_hash = {"attr1"=>"val1", "attr2"=>"val2"}
d = OpenStruct.new(attr_hash)
p d.attr1 #=> "val1"
```